# Best way to pass css class attribute to grails fields plugin custom template

Tags: grails, plugins

Working with the Grails Fields plugin, I have some custom templates for which I'd like to pass in an attribute named class (for CSS styling).

e.g. Here's what I want to do:

```
<f:field property="someProperty" class="someCustomCssClass" />
```

The problem is I can't simply look for the "class" property in the custom template, as that's a reserved word.  I'd rather not use a different attribute name like "cssClass", because then I can't easily swap between default fields template usage and custom fields template usage.

The only thing I can think of so far is to parse the "widget" property and grab the class out of that String, but is there a better way to grab the value of the class attribute in a custom fields template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
pageScope["class"]
```

Comment: Could you explain it?

Comment: Sure - here's a snippet from one of my overridden templates:

`<input type="text" <%= pageScope["class"] ? "class='${pageScope["class"]}'" : ""%> <%=readonly ? "readonly=readonly" : ""%> etc... />`

Normally you can just look for a attribute by name, as in the readonly attribute.  But class doesn't normally work...it's in the pageScope properties Map though, so you can pull it out of there using its key name.

Comment: Hm. It doesn't work for me. 

I use twitter bootstrap with this template https://gist.github.com/VladimirHavenchyk/6725547

How can I set class for widget?

Comment: Here's a full gist example.  The _field.gsp in this example is a String type override.  e.g. It's located in /views/_fields/string/_field.gsp.
The template allows more than just the class, and it's also using bootstrap 3.  HTH.

Comment: Why do you not use input-class for field?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following attribute in the f:field tag and is working on version 1.3 of Fields Plugin for Grails.

```
<f:field property="someProperty" input-class="someCustomCssClass anotherCustomCssClass" />
```

If you want to add another custom attribute, you can do it using the prefix name "input-" and adding the required name after the prefix. All the attributes that have the prefix "input-" are passed to the widget as its attributes.

If you already has been [customized the filed rendering](http://freeside.co/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html), this is when you create the default template in views/_fields/_field.gsp , you can pass your own attributes to the field adding them in the template file. Te following is the template that I use for [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). In this case, I'm passing the form-control class to the field.

```
<div class="form-group ${invalid ? 'has-error has-feedback' : required && value ? 'has-success has-feedback' : ''}">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="${property}">${label}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <f:input bean="${bean}" property="${property}" class="form-control"/>
        <g:if test="${invalid}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
            <span class="help-block">${errors.join('<br>')}</span>
        </g:if>
        <g:else test="${invalid}">
            <g:if test="${required && value}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
            </g:if>
        </g:else>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to render the default field, you have to remove the line:

```
<f:input bean="${bean}" property="${property}" class="form-control"/>
```

and the replace them with

```
${raw(widget)}
```